# .Net getting enum type through reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, enums

I'm having an structure with a bunch of properties, all enums.

What I like to do is iterate through the properties and get the underlying type of the enum, or the enums list of values. So I can create dropdownlists for them without writing code for each of them.

I managed to get the selected value, name of enum, description etc. But I'm stuck on this part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some code to show how you are accessing the properties? There is an Enum.GetValues(type) to get the values of an enum.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily iterate through each property of a class using reflection and determine which of them are enums and which are not (by using IsEnum property of the PropertyType class).
For each enum that you have found you can then check its underlying type.

The you could use such a generic extension method:

```
   public static IDictionary<string, string> EnumToDictionary(this Type t)
    {
        if (t == null) throw new NullReferenceException();
        if (!t.IsEnum) throw new InvalidCastException("object is not an Enumeration");

        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(t);
        Array values = Enum.GetValues(t);

        return (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, names.Length)
                select new { Key = names[i], Value = (int)values.GetValue(i) })
                    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value.ToString());
    }
```

And then call it like this for each enum type that you have found in your class:

```
var result = typeOfEnum.EnumToDictionary();
```

Where typeOfEnum is the underlying type of an enum that you have found while iterating through the properties of a class.

You can then use the result to populate appropriate dropdownlists with enum's names and values.